# Charge form with conditional validation

Tags: plugins, plugin-charge

Is there a way to create conditional validation on 2 fields related to the same desired input using the Charge plugin? The Reason plugin does not work when defining fields in the CP->Charge->Settings->Field view.

I have a set of radio buttons and a text field for the user to input a chosen value. The user can either choose the buttons or type in a numeric value into the text field. However, it's possible that the user can simply *not* choose a value from neither the radio buttons nor type in a value into the text field.

I see in the documentation that there is an [`onBeforeCharge` event](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge/usage/developer/hooks-and-events#event-onBeforeCharge) that can be used, so perhaps I could create a custom validation rule there, but I don't know if that should be defined in a template or in Javascript. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey @tofirius – feel free to [add a feature request](https://github.com/mmikkel/Reasons-Craft/issues) for Charge support in Reasons, and I might get around to it (sooner or later, but less chance I forget...)

Comment: Sounds good! I submitted the feature request. Thanks for the clever plugin, by the way. As soon as I'm up to speed, I hope to start writing some plugins of my own.